# System.ArgumentException: The 'ClientID' option must be provided error while trying to create IIS website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am brand new to .NET web development, and I have been tasked with making some improvements to an existing IIS website/application, which was created by another developer about 5 years, long before I came to my current company. The web application is working and functional now, and the files that it references are on an FTP server that no one here has access to, so I am unable to reference the current code in order to remove issues with mine. However, the developer did leave behind a half-baked version of the project on our file server, which I have been referencing for the time being. I have set up my own FTP server and website for the application, which run just fine in IIS, along with a Visual Studios .cs project to house my code, which publishes the code to my FTP server with no issue. However, when I go to click the 'Browse' button on my website in IIS, I continue to recieve the same error over and over again:

"Server Error in '/' Application"

Description: The 'ClientID' option must be provided

Stack Trace:
[ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.]
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationMiddleware..ctor(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app, GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions options) +732
lambda_method(Closure , OwinMiddleware , IAppBuilder , GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions ) +93

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +132
System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args) +160
Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.BuildInternal(Type signature) +321
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +792 Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +51
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +101
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +139
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +160
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +202
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +1089
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +232
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +426

After some extensive research, I have found little to no documentation on this error that does not involve some sort of Azure AD clientID and clientSecret, which I am convinced are not used in this project because they are not listed anywhere in the project files that were left behind. I have, however, identified 3 files that reference the ClientID parameter/value in some way shape or form. I have listed the one I believe is the culprit below:

1. Start.Auth.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using LocationTracking.Providers;
using LocationTracking.Models;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure;


namespace LocationTracking
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
                
                ,AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider  //added
                {
                    OnCreate = context =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Access token created: {context.Token}");
                    },
                    OnReceive = context =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Access token received: {context.Token}");
                    }
                }
                
            };

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

            //Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            /*
            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
                clientId: "",
                clientSecret: "");

            app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
                consumerKey: "",
                consumerSecret: "");

            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
                appId: "",
                appSecret: "");

            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret = ""
            });
            */
        }
    }
}
```

This file hardcodes the value of PublicCLientId to "self", which is a valid value for the ClientID parameter, but it never seems to be referenced when the website is accessed.

I have also tried attaching the Visual Studios debugger to the IIS process running the website, but that has accomplished nothing because when I set breakpoints anywhere in the Startup.Auth.cs file (or any files for that matter), they are never hit before the ClientID error is thrown.

Am I missing something? Does my problem even make sense? Please help.

Any suggestions for this error?

Comment: We don't know what your application is. According to the above information you provide, perhaps you should check the configuration settings of Google Oauth2 middleware in the application and make sure that the clientid attribute settings are correct. I suggest that you can find developers who are more experienced in your project for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.] Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationMiddleware
```

This error looks like it's related to missing OAuth authentication configuration. The version on your server likely has things like ClientID/Secret stored in a settings file somewhere, the version you are running locally does not have these settings so you get this error.

Check the web.config on the server and anything else that looks like it might be storing settings and replicate that locally.

Comment: If I don't have access to the server containing the code currently in production, is there any other way I would be able to access the settings file? I would assume not since it contains sensitive information, but I'm hoping there's a workaround of some sort.

Comment: If you can't get access to the original web.config your only other option is to generate new ClientID/Secret with whatever you're authenticating against (presumably google). If you don't have access to the account which set up the authentication on googles side originally you might have to set up a new one. If that's appropriate to your situation or not and what might be lost along the way I don't know.